# PayPal checkout.js: Express checkout with JavascriptButtonAPI without PayPal account

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I try to add an express-checkout button with the checkout.js V4 integration (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/). It works fine.

But now I need to allow customers to pay without a PayPal account.

I have tried with the following configuration:

- use sandbox and the production mode.
- valid email
- valid creditcard
- set "allow without PayPal account" in the PayPal payment options
- business account

I found different solutions based on the deprecated NVP/SOAP integration (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECUIRequirements/) but that's not what I need.

Is there a possibility to allow users to pay without a PayPal account with the express-checkout checkout.js V4 integration?

Comment: Hey, have you found a way eventually?